# Preserving training/validation split after restarting training from a checkpoint with TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have written a TensorFlow training loop which does validation at the end of each epoch. At the start of the training I split my dataset into training and validation subsets (about 85%-15% split). My dataset actually consists of audio samples stored in small chunks on disk, and I randomly shuffle the entire dataset before splitting, so I get a completely even distribution over the training and validation subsets. Problem is, if I restart the training from a given checkpoint the random shuffle occurs again, and I suspect this can lead to data contamination - the validation phase is potentially going to be processing bits of the dataset that the network has aleady been trained on. I think I'm seeing this affecting the loss and accuracy of the training after retsrating, but it's hard to tell.

I can't find any info on this specific issue on the web, but my proposed solution is to cache the names of the files in the validation split to a file, and if restarting load them from there. Is there a better solution?

For clarity, I am using the tf.data.Dataset API, building both training and validation datasets with a simple dataset pipeline which begins by reading samples from the files on disk.

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/splits#reproducibility

Comment: @Chris Thsnks - I don't use a pre-packaged dataset, I juat use the tf.data dataset API. But I guess my proposed solution is equivalent to that, since it would seem to guarantee consistency.

Comment: As is, the question needs details & clarity - details such the ones you have just provided should be already in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the seed of the shuffling, the order will be consistant:

```
import tensorflow as tf

for _ in range(5):
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.range(1, 10).shuffle(4, seed=42).batch(3)
    for i in ds:
        print(i)
    print()
```

```
tf.Tensor([4 1 2], shape=(3,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([7 3 6], shape=(3,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([5 9 8], shape=(3,), dtype=int64)

tf.Tensor([4 1 2], shape=(3,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([7 3 6], shape=(3,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([5 9 8], shape=(3,), dtype=int64)

tf.Tensor([4 1 2], shape=(3,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([7 3 6], shape=(3,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([5 9 8], shape=(3,), dtype=int64)

tf.Tensor([4 1 2], shape=(3,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([7 3 6], shape=(3,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([5 9 8], shape=(3,), dtype=int64)

tf.Tensor([4 1 2], shape=(3,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([7 3 6], shape=(3,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([5 9 8], shape=(3,), dtype=int64)
```

So, all you need is the list of files in the same order each time, which you can do with `tf.data.Dataset.list_files`, and set `shuffle=False`:

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(r'C:\Users\User\Downloads\*', shuffle=False)
```